# Related questions under Creative Commons?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, licensing, creative-commons

Stack Exchange releases its user-generated content in a data dump under a Creative Commons license—this is an incredible resource for researchers like myself, and as far as I know no other site has made their data so readily available to this degree.

There is some data however that is publicly accessible through the API but not in the data dump (e.g. related questions). Is this data also covered under the Creative Commons license, or does some other protocol need to be followed for the data to be republished?

Comment: I don't follow what exactly you're trying to get at here. All of the related questions are other questions on our network, all of which would be under the same license. We simply don't dump those lists when creating the data dump, probably because it's a lot of additional information to include with every single question. Could you clarify what exactly you are not sure about being licensed?

Comment: "as far as I know no other site has made their data so readily available to this degree": Wikimedia does this for their projects (like Wikipedia), too: [data dumps](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps), [data downloads](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/), [Wikipedia database download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download), …. And all MediaWiki instances typically allow the download of all content via the API.